# _GET method php

Tags: php, html, get

I am making a textEditor website just for fun for me and I got most of what I am going to do down. But now, I am wondering I am having issue with a transfer of data by `_GET` method in php and won't write to my files if it is `&lt;` (<). It has to be `<` for some odd reason. Is there an easy method to override this when it transfer it? I could find some way, but wanted to know if there was a simple way.

EDITOR FILE:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Web Editor</title>
<link href="controller.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/editor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="platform">
<div class="head"><div class="file"><p>File: <div id="file">hello.html</div></p></div></div>
<div class="hotbar"><img src="images/save.png" class="hotbarImage" onClick="save()" />

</div>
<div class="editor"><div contenteditable="true" style="height:100%; overflow:scroll;" id="editPad" ></div></div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$data = $_GET['data'];

$f = fopen($dir,"w");
fwrite($f,$data);
fclose($f);
?>
```

SAVE JS FILE:

```
function save() {
    var dir = document.getElementById("file").innerHTML;
    var data = document.getElementById("editPad").innerHTML;
    window.location = "save.php?dir="+dir+"&data="+data;
}
```

It's not complete just cause I started today, but was working on some of the basics functions.

Comment: GET is a bad fit for this use case... use POST

Comment: Was post the better one in this case? I honestly couldn't remember it been a while since I used POST and GET.

Comment: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) may help, but we'd have to know more to provide specific answers.

Comment: Would you mind showing some code that can demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Is it just me, or does writing user posted data directly to a file with no sanitization seem like a really really bad idea to anyone else?

Comment: Eh, not done yet. Just working on basic things. Not like it gonna go public. Lol.

Comment: @Matt For your updated question, try something like `"?dir="+encodeURIComponent(dir)+"&data="+encodeURIComponent(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

`html_entity_decode('&lt;')`